# Can I draw a grid of dots within a custom WPF canvas control?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, custom-controls

I've built a custom control that inherits from canvas. It uses the ArrangeOverride method to add drag drop functionality to all child elements, and this includes grid snapping to 50 pixels and some other custom behaviour such as persisting the element positions.

What I'd really like to do is extend this so that while dragging, it shows a grid of dots or crosses in the background so that you can see where the snap points are.

However, I can't modify the template of the control because it's a panel. I tried making it a custom control that contains a canvas, and passing the IEnumerable items source through, but it became really tricky to pick up on the collection changing, and also the collection then contained models and not framework elements.

So I'm not sure which path I should be taking. It feels as though there may be a very simple solution that I've overlooked, so I'm open to suggestions!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar once: drawing the grid lines on the UserControl, and then adding controls on top of it. It was for a simple scheduler app used to assign who will be working what shift in the current month. I had to have column headers (days) and row headers (people) and a scrollable grid inside, to which I could add/remove controls. I don't know to what extent my solution will help you, but here it is.

I use `HeaderedScrollViewer` from [here](https://softnotes.wordpress.com/2009/11/07/headeredscrollviewer-in-wpf/). `UCHeader` is a `UserControl` with rotated textboxes with dates. The magic happens in the `UC_GridLines`.

```
<Grid>
    <lib:HeaderedScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="AliceBlue">
    <lib:HeaderedScrollViewer.TopHeader>
        <lib:UCHeader Name="ucHeader"/>
    </lib:HeaderedScrollViewer.TopHeader>
    <lib:HeaderedScrollViewer.LeftHeader>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Name="spRows" />
        </Border>
    </lib:HeaderedScrollViewer.LeftHeader>
    <Grid Name="gridContentAll">
        <Border Canvas.ZIndex="1"  Background="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                <Grid ClipToBounds="True" Name="gridContent"  Background="Transparent" />
        </Border>
        <Border Canvas.ZIndex="0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White">
            <lib:UC_GridLines Name="ucGridLines" BorderThickness="0"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</lib:HeaderedScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Important here are:

- Setting `Background="Transparent"` for the control that is containing child controls
- Setting ZIndex correctly, so the controls are shown over the grid.
- Setting `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` and `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on the root element (e.g. the WIndow)

UC_GridLines in its .xaml file has nothing (only `<Grid></Grid>`). Drawing the grid lines happens in the codebehind:

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        // VM contains data of the grid, used to draw gridlines
        // such as number of days etc.
        if (this.VM == null)
        {
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);
            return;
        }
        double dpiFactor = 1;
        try
        {
            Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this)
                     .CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
            dpiFactor = 1 / m.M11;
        }
        catch { }

        Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1 * dpiFactor);
        double halfPenWidth = pen.Thickness / 2;

        GuidelineSet guidelines = new GuidelineSet();

        double width = this.VM.Days.Count * this.VM.DayWidth - 16 * (this.VM.DayWidth / 24);
        double height = this.VM.RowHeight * rowCount;

        for (int i = 1; i < this.VM.Days.Count; i++)
        {
            guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(i * this.VM.DayWidth + halfDashPenWidth);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(i * this.VM.RowHeight + halfPenWidth);
        }

        drawingContext.PushGuidelineSet(guidelines);

        for (int i = 1; i < this.VM.Days.Count; i++)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawLine(dashpen, new Point(i * this.VM.DayWidth, 0), new Point(i * this.VM.DayWidth, height));
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, i * this.VM.RowHeight), new Point(width, i * this.VM.RowHeight));
        }

        drawingContext.Pop();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Arie - that's really helpful. I've just overriden the OnRender method for the custom control and added a grid. Any idea how I could only show the grid while the user is actively dragging though? That render method only gets called initially, and then when I resize the control. Ideally it would be great to be able to show and hide it.

Comment: Never mind - it's actually fine just staying there. I've made it quite subtle. I also had to add base.OnRender(drawingContext) to the end, otherwise the drag/grid snapping performance was really bad for some reason. Thanks again for the code sample.